# web hosting for spring and hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-hosting

I have to host a web application built using JSP, Java 6, **Spring 3, Hibernate 3**, mySql, Tomcat 6.

I am new to hosting a web application and have some queries:-

1. Can anyone please guide me on this, specially from the **Spring and Hibernate** point of view?
2. What are the issues raised during hosting/running an Hibernate & Spring application ?
3. Will any host providing Java hosting also provide support for Spring and Hibernate?

Answer (score 9):

You may use a cloud provider for that. There are a lot. Amazon web services is the leader on the market but it's moving fast (and you have a free micro instance for one year to try). Oracle just entered the ring for example. Rakspace is a big one too and there are a lot of others.

Then you may decide between IAAS and PAAS. Basically with PAAS you don't install tomcat or mysql yourself. There you have solutions like Red Hat Openshift, Vmware Cloudfoundry, Amazon beanstalkC cloudbees, Microsoft Azure.
With IAAS, you have a virtual machine. Maybe you can start by this to move up the stack and try PAAS later.

Cloud is the future of hosting. Renting a physical machine will disappear shortly. PAAS is believed to be the future of cloud. So you should try the cloud. There are tons of tutorials on this.

Comment: I am building a Maven Spring MVC Web Application on Tomcat 9. I am confused with the options available in AWS. Can you help me to choose which pack is suitable for my Web Application along with MySQL db. I prefer a free option for now, may be I can move to a paid one later. (I use Eclipse)

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala You may look at https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/?p=tile. Another option is to use ec2. You get a free tier for one year with limited resources. This permits to try and learn. I may also advise you a book: https://www.manning.com/books/amazon-web-services-in-action.

Comment: Thank you so much for the resources. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several PaaS where you can deploy a Spring application. However, not in all of them you will have support for the same containers. CloudBees is a Java PaaS where you can deploy your application in Tomcat, Jboss, Glassfish and Jetty. You have the several containers that they support [here](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack).

Specifically for Spring you have this [official documentation](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Springframework) and also this step by step [guide](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/10/step-by-step-guide-about-how-to-deploy.html) on a blog.

They also provide two ClickStart as an example:

- [PetClinic ClickStart](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/spring-petclinic-clickstart)
- [BeesShop ClickStart](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/bees-shop-clickstart)

As always... try different platforms and just choose the one which meets your needs.